# std::sort throws Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, segmentation-fault

Here's my code

```
bool cmp (const char &a, const char &b)
{   
    if ((int) a == (int) b)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if ((int) a > (int) b)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}   
std::sort(
        dfaVector.at(0).getSigma().begin(),
        dfaVector.at(0).getSigma().end(),
        cmp);
```

`getSigma()` returns `std::vector<char>` , and they aren't empty - I checked it. I can post stack trace from gdb if you want. I'm using g++ 4.8, OS Mint 14

**ANSWER**

As suggested by @livingissuicide the problem was that `getSigma()` needs to return a reference(i.e. sth constant, @PhoenixX_2). The explanation **why**  it needs to return a reference (and why just a simple copy doesn't suffice) is because

> The problem is that there are two calls to getSigma, producing two different vectors. A pair of iterators passed to sort is not a valid range - the two iterators point into different containers.

Explanation courtesy of @IgorTandetnik .

Comment: you know you could rewrite your `cmp` function as `return a < b;`, right? Readability matters. :)

Comment: Or just `std::less<int>()`. And ***formatting*** matters too. A whole lot. Anyways, the problem is in the code not shown

Comment: or even leave it out entirely, as `std::less` is the default in any case. :)

Comment: @jalf, well, `int` is different from `char` and depending on whether char is signed or unsigned, it could lead to differences in behavior depending on implementation? I'm not even trying to reason about this further, because it's not very interesting.

Comment: @jalf - it was originally as you said, I just wanted to make sure I'm not getting the logic wrong so I rewrote it explicitly.
sehe - what am I doing wrong with formatting ? Could you elaborate more?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> getSigma() returns std::vector< char >

Make sure your getSigma() function returns a reference (std::vector< char >&) rather than a copy!

Comment: This fixes it, no segmentation fault now. Why does it fix it though - would you explain?

Comment: @livingissuicide: wrong. The temporary is destroyed at the semicolon, it lives long enough for the `sort` call. The problem is that there are **two** calls to `getSigma`, producing two different vectors. A pair of iterators passed to `sort` is not a valid range - the two iterators point into different containers.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'll put this in the answer for clarification.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Your are right, what I wrote in the comments was totally wrong!

Comment: I explained the immediate cause of the crash. But that's not why `getSigma` should return a reference. The real reason is this: crash or no crash, it is rather pointless to sort a temporary copy of the vector that is going to be destroyed soon afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `dfaVector` isn't empty.  Also make sure `getSigma()` returns something constant (a reference).